# Excel VBA Variable Declaration Ambersand

Tags: excel, vba, variables, declaration

In a great VBA code example @https://medium.com/@daniel.ferry/excel-vba-get-unique-values-easily-592162f52c6e there is followng Variable declaration:

```
Function DistinctVals(arr, Optional col = 1)
    Dim i&, v: v = arr
```

Everthing works fine in Windows but on Mac there is a ByRef argument type mismatch.
My question is not about the mismatch - there is even Dictionary not working on Mac, but it's about the never seen before and can't find with search engine "**Dim i&**" Declaration. In other languages the ambersand stands for Reference, but a) this does not make sense in this context and b) it's not documented - at least I can't find any.

[image: Dim declaration with ambersand]

Thanks in advance

Comment: It means `Dim i As Long`.

Comment: For a MAC dictionary alternative, you might try using [this](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means `Long` type. From [VBA reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables):

`The shorthand for the types is: % -integer; & -long; @ -currency; # -double; ! -single; $ -string`

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response! [ I had already been at this site but had overseen  this part ]

Comment: @user3665647, yeah. Some information from documentation is not so easy to find :)